# Early 2000s cartoon show where villain is a blue cat

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was set in animals universe and there were no humans. I think there was a villain who was a blue cat and used to make gadgets. And protagonist was a superhero but kept their identity hidden to public. Villain used to try to defeat the hero but always failed. There was nothing sort of special about the show other than I used to watch it regularly in mornings during my childhood. I'm from Nepal and I think it was aired in Nickelodeon but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What country did you see this in?  Can you describe the animation style?

Comment: What type of animal was the hero? And did the animals live in a human-style world with modern buildings, cars, businesses and whatnot?

Comment: I almost feel like this might be S.W.A.T. Kats, though the particulars might be jumbled up.  Megakat City was populated with anthropomorphic cats, and the two main protagonists wore blue jumpsuits and flew a futuristic fighter jet with a lot of gadgets cobbled together by one of them, but their real identities as maintenance men for the police force (I think) were kept hidden.  I don't recall a consistent "big bad", but I'm guessing if there was one, it'd be a cat.  Edit:  there is an archvillian called Dark Kat who has a blue/dark purple coloration.

Comment: The animals lived in human style world with buildings, schools and vehicles. I think the hero was also a student. It's animation style was typical cartoon type like Dora the explorer. There was not much story. I just wanna rewatch it for nostalgic purpose.

Comment: If you want to self-answer, the way to do it is by writing posting an answer, not editing the original question

Answer (score 3):

Could this have been *[Krypto the Superdog](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0437018/)* from 2005?

One of the most prominent villains is Mechanikat, a cyborg cat with a purple (not quite blue) colour scheme. Also pictured on the right is Krypto himself, who is indeed a superhero:

[image]

What doesn't match is that the series is set on Earth; Krypto's human owner Kevin is a prominent character.

Comment: Sorry it's wrong. They're not from marvel or DC.